# Make Access Form Update With Buttons

Tags: database, ms-access, macros

I constructed an Access database for a group of end-users. This database is composed of one table, tblInventory, and several queries for them to edit their data quickly/easily. One of my queries, for example, is:

```
UPDATE tblInventory SET Amount = Amount-[Enter Amount]
WHERE ((([tblInventory].Equiptment_Name)=[Enter Name]));
```

This worked great in my opinion, but I have to please the end-user after all. They requested that I make a form and use buttons to update the data in the table for them. I have the form laid out like this:
[image]

The Equipment_Name and Amount boxes pull their information from my table, which has categories named that. My Unbound textbox field is where I would like them to be able to enter the number of the given part they would like to take out of inventory. The button should be to run my query above, but instead of prompting for inputs I would like it to use what they entered into the textbox. I've tried many different things and searched many different sites but cannot find what I'm looking for.

P.S Equiptment_Name and Amount are the only 2 datafields in the table besides other fields I have in the table to serve as more lenient ways to search for data when they entered in names. These fields are called things such as Alt_Name1 and have no real relevance to the form.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple ways you can do it but the simplest way is:

1. Build your query as a predefined query(ies)
2. Build a Macro that disabled warnings then executes your query or queries in the order you wish to execute them.
3. Go to the form Define the button.
4. Go to the event tab.
5. Build an event
6. Set the OnClick Event to the name of the Macro.
7. Save and Test.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? It looks like you're deffinately steering me down a good path, so I tried to use information from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx . It explains it in a little more detail, but I'm getting stuck on my macro's design. The issue is that I'm making a parameter and an alias which it asks for, but I'm making these wrong. Errors pop up and tell me things such as,"You cannot implement this function." or "You need an alias to implement this..".

Comment: @Brad I thought about this and I just want to make sure we are not making this more complex than it needs to be. Immediate thoughts, you state that you need to deduct from inventory. So instead of just using accessing normal update the inventory of 50 to 48 (having the user mentally calculate it) you want to do a -2 or +2 to modify the inventory is that correct? If so (and this off the top of my head) instead of directly accessing the table in the form use a query view, then drive an update query in your macro of the actual table.